# Access javascript variable declared/defined/initialized in ajax page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I make an ajax call with:

## index.php

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'abc.php',
  success:function(returned_data)
  {
     // returned_data  contains HTML + javascript code
     // I'd like to access the javascript variable here
     // refer to abc.php's code to see what variable
     // somehow access "new_variable" here
  }
})
```

## abc.php

```
<table id="first_table">
 <tr>
   .
   .
   .
  <!-- some un-related td content -->
 </tr>
</table>
<script>
  new_variable = $('#first_table').dataTable();
  // now I want new_variable to be available in index.php page; i.e. inside the success
  // function of the ajax method
</script>
```

Can this be achieved? Or any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: May be you can try with `document.write(new_variable);` in your abc.php

Comment: It might be easier to send JSON data to the server, which would include the variable.

Comment: Nevermind. I solved it. Using `console.log(new_variable)` inside `success` function is giving me the result. Don't know why it didn't work earlier..Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, the problem seemed to vanish by itself. I don't know what minor change I did or didn't, but simply using:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'abc.php',
  success:function(returned_data)
  {
     console.log(new_variable);
  }
})
```

printed the result appropriately...which didn't happen earlier before asking this question. What's more is since it is global variable, I could access it outside this ajax function too xD

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead:

```
   $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'abc.php',
        success:function(data)
        {
            var new_variable = $(data).find('#first_table').dataTable();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Updated my question to reflect what the variable exactly contains

Comment: I believe that is solution is still possbile asuming that you load dataTable when Index.php is executed.

Comment: Nevermind. I solved it. Using `console.log(new_variable)` inside `success` function is giving me the result. Don't know why it didn't work earlier..Thanks for your time though